# The click automation on phantonjs is not working

Tags: phantomjs

The official example about clicking on phantomjs is not working:
http://phantomjs.org/page-automation.html

I've tried as follows:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  while (true) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) { break; }
  }
}

var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://example.com/', function() {
  page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
      $("a").click();
    });
    sleep(3000);
    page.render('screenshot.png');
    phantom.exit()
  });
});
```

but I get a screenshot of http://example.com/, instead of https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved (the target of the click).

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how jQuery handles the clicking, but accessing an element via vanilla JS and "clicking" it will work:

```
page.open('http://example.com/', function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        document.querySelector("a").click();
    });
});
```

It's not reliable to wait for an arbitrary period of time, better to use a callback that fires *every time* a page has finished loading:

```
page.onLoadFinished = function(){

    // What page are we currently on?
    var url = page.evaluate(function(){
        return document.location.href;
    });

    console.log(url);

    if(url.indexOf("iana") !== -1)
    {
        page.render('example.png');
        phantom.exit();
    }
}
```

---

*A compulsory notу about PhantomJS: if you can, consider migrating to [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) or any other modern headless solution, because PhantomJS is already very obsolete and it will be harder and harder to maintain scrips in the future*

Comment: thanks! the problem was, I think, that my dummy sleep function did not allow the browser to evaluate the click event.

Comment: thanks for the puppeteer link. i am currently using Selenium with the chromedriver. I was trying phantomjs in order to avoid installing Chrome on the headless ubuntu without an admin account. But I agree that it's better to use chrome, and not so complicated: https://blog.testproject.io/2018/02/20/chrome-headless-selenium-python-linux-servers/